# awk extract "Matthew" from mtjoseph:6/MKTCzMS/YU.:10974:10060:Matthew

Tags: linux, awk

How to extract "**Matthew**" from "mtjoseph:6/MKTCzMS/YU.:10974:10060:**Matthew**"

Comment: Doesn't this fits more to serverfault?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
echo "mtjoseph:6/MKTCzMS/YU.:10974:10060:Matthew"| awk -F ':' '{print $5}'
```

Comment: Googled for *awk split by char*, returned here, oh! my answer is already posted! ;)

Comment: or `print $NF` to generically take the last field

Answer (score 0):

I find  echo "mtjoseph:6/MKTCzMS/YU.:10974:10060:Matthew"| cut -d: -f5 simpler.

Comment: Someone I highly respect once said "there is a whole generation of programmers who think awk is just a synonym for cut(1)".

Answer (score 0):

Or, just let the shell do it (assuming bash)

```
entry="mtjoseph:6/MKTCzMS/YU.:10974:10060:Matthew"
name="${entry##*:}"
echo "$name" # ==> Matthew
```